# Can't get express to work with Redis

Tags: node.js, express, redis

I'm using **Express 4.x**.  I declare **Redis** here:

```
var app = require('express')()
, express = require('express')
, connect = require('connect')
, http = require('http').Server(app)
, path = require('path')
, request = require("request")
, io = require('socket.io')(http);


// Cookie and Session Reqs:
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
var sessionStore = new RedisStore();
```

And I set up my **session**:

```
app.use(session({
    secret: "xxxxx",
    store: sessionStore,    
    key: 'sid',
    cookie: {secure: false, maxAge: 600000},
}));
```

And I use my session variable in one of my **routes**:

```
app.get('/public/', function(req, res) {
    req.session.sessionAccessCode = "not set yet";
    res.redirect("index.html");
});
```

When I remove the `store: sessionStore` line, there are no problems and I can test that the session variable works.  But if I have it, I'm given an error:

`TypeError: Cannot set property 'sessionAccessCode' of undefined`

Any ideas why **Redis** isn't working?

Comment: Is redis listening on localhost, port 6379? Check with `redis-cli` and/or `sudo netstat -nlp`.

Comment: @mscdex Tried redis-cli; "Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start redis first somehow. Depending on how you installed redis, it could be as simple as starting a `redis` service if you installed via a package for example.

Comment: Thanks, it was this problem in the end.  I started Redis as a Daemon and, hey presto.